# Package RandomWalk and Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, randomwalk

I am trying to draw some random walks in my $\LaTeX$ doc, but I don't know how to:

1. Plot two or more `\RandomWalk` in one picture (starting in the same point)
2. Construct a coordinate system around the plots

The code I use right now:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{randomwalk}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\RandomWalk{number= 50, length=5pt, angles = {45,315}, degree} %The random walk I want to plot
\\
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=center,draw=blue,inner sep=0,every picture/.style={draw=red, thick}](randdes)
      {\RandomWalk{number= 50, length=5pt, angles = {45,315}, degree},
      \RandomWalk{number= 50, length=5pt, angles = {45,315}, degree}};
\end{tikzpicture} %Gives me two random walks next to each other in a blue box...

\end{document}
```

[image: Pdf for the code]

If there is a better way to plot the random walks, please do tell.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not make `\RandomWalk`s start in the same point. Here is an alternative solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{randomwalk}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=10,
ymin=-5, ymax=5,
]
\draw[red] (0,0) \foreach \i in {1,...,50}{ -- ++({(2*random(0,1)-1)*45}:5pt) };
\draw[green] (0,0) \foreach \i in {1,...,50}{ -- ++({(2*random(0,1)-1)*45}:5pt) };
\draw[blue] (0,0) \foreach \i in {1,...,50}{ -- ++({(2*random(0,1)-1)*45}:5pt) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with three random walks]

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @PapierFlieger: Does this solve your problem? Please accept answer.